# Undefined reference error when using igraph

Tags: c++, ubuntu, undefined, igraph

I am using graph-0.6 on ubuntu 12.04

IDE Eclipse CDT C++

Have this example code from http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch04s02.html#igraph_add_vertices
When I try to compile I get

> undefined reference to: igraph_vector_init and the rest of the functions.

It finds the header file and can create a graph structure (igraph_g t;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <igraph.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
igraph_t g;

igraph_attribute_table_t *
igraph_i_set_attribute_table(const igraph_attribute_table_t * table);


igraph_t g1;
igraph_vector_t v1;
int ret;

/* Create a graph */
igraph_vector_init(&v1, 8);
VECTOR(v1)[0]=0; VECTOR(v1)[1]=1;
VECTOR(v1)[2]=1; VECTOR(v1)[3]=2;
VECTOR(v1)[4]=2; VECTOR(v1)[5]=3;
VECTOR(v1)[6]=2; VECTOR(v1)[7]=2;
igraph_create(&g1, &v1, 0, 0);
igraph_vector_destroy(&v1);

/* Add more vertices */
igraph_add_vertices(&g1, 10, 0);
if (igraph_vcount(&g1) != 14) {
return 1;
}

igraph_destroy(&g1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's probably a library you didn't link to. I haven't used igraph, so I don't know off the top of my head, but that's a common source of these errors.

Comment: installed igraph and used: 

GCC C++ Compiler, choose Directories. Then: Include paths: /usr/local/include/igraph 

GCC C++ Linker, choose Libraries. Then: Libraries: igraph, Library search path: /usr/local/lib

Comment: *For compiling this program you need a C compiler, if this is called gcc and the previous code is saved in file igraph_test.c, you will need a command like this:*

`gcc igraph_test.c -I/usr/local/igraph -L/usr/local/lib -ligraph -o igraph_test` The `-ligraph` means you need to link to that library (`igraph.lib` or whatever it may be), whether from the command line itself, or through your IDE. For a reference to the doc I pulled it from, http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch03s01.html

Comment: used this to configure eclipse http://code.google.com/p/igraph/wiki/IgraphInEclipse

Comment: I can compile fine with the eclipse c++ IDE, it just complains about certain functions from the igraph lib

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine, but after compilation comes linking. You're getting linker errors because it can't find the definitions for the prototypes the compiler used (presumably because you didn't tell it where the definitions are via linking to igraph's library).

Comment: Set up the GCC C++ Linker options:
Library search path: /usr/local/lib

Comment: @StefanPantea I would try to compile and link from the command line. That would tell you whether the error is in the way you've built/installed the library or in the way you've set up your eclipse project.

Comment: I get the same thing when I compile with the terminal

Comment: Using what command? Did you include `-ligraph`?

Comment: g++ igTest.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -o igTest

Comment: OK, no library referenced there, you need something like `-ligraph`.